# How to change borderColor in Spark Button in runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, colors, border

I need to set up some parameters in spark Buttons. I tried setStyle, but it doesn't work with borderColor.

My code is something like this:

```
for each (var prop:XML in option.elements()){   
    var but:spark.components.Button = new spark.components.Button();
    but.label=prop
    but.width=button_width
    but.setStyle("verticalAlign",'middle')
    but.setStyle('chromeColor', '#'+arrayRGB[j]) // arrayRGB have the colors i need
    but.setStyle('borderColor','#'+arrayRGB[i]) //<-- Don't work
    
    container.addElement(but)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you can create a new SkinClass for the button, set the Rect property in there, and give it a border, that's your best option. Then you can just to but.setSkinClass and control it from there.

Think of the button's "skin" has a child object to the button object and not just a property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dominic, but i have a doubt. Can i modify one property of the SkinClass whit AS3?? or it's necesary to create the entire class whit the 4 states and more?

Comment: You don't HAVE to create the whole class, just make sure the instance of the SkinClass you create contains a modified Rect border property. It's not that big an issue. You want to create dynamic buttons. Create one supporting instance of SkinClass's that can be assigned to each button with the style you want. Put that into a method. Welcome to spark.